# jQuery Remove Brackets/Text from Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, e-commerce

Here is a snippet of HTML that loads on the site, I cannot change this as it's loaded via code blocks in 3D Cart:

```
    <div class="opt-field">
                <label for="text56">4kg - $19 [+$19.00]</label>
                <input type="text" size="3" name="text56" value="0"><br>

                <label for="text58">8kg/18lb - $29 - Currently Out of Stock [+$29.00]</label>
                <input type="text" size="3" name="text58" value="0"><br>

                <label for="text59">12kg/26lb - $39 - Currently Out of Stock [+$39.00]</label>
                <input type="text" size="3" name="text59" value="0"><br>
</div>
```

And I want to remove the automatically generated [+$price] that is attached to each label. I have tried many variations I have found on here but nothing seems to affect it.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var str = $('.opt-field label');
        var r = str.replace(/[(\[].*?[)\]] */g, "");
        $('label').html(r);
    });
```

Here is the jsfiddle I have been trying it on: https://jsfiddle.net/32rch0n9/1/

Thanks for any help/suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reference: [https://jsfiddle.net/32rch0n9/5/][1]

Your regular expression works. The catch is you have to apply for each label. Refer to the above fiddle for sample.


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/32rch0n9/5/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is your JS code, you are not working with the list of labels.

```
$('.opt-field label').each(function(index, item){
        console.log($(item).text());
        var r = $(item).text().replace(/[(\[].*?[)\]] */g, "");
        $(item).html(r);
    });
```

Comment: Your code is working to remove the square bracket and it's value inside it. Can you let me give the code or give me hind to do this same thing to remove the round bracket and it's value inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove the brackets you can use the following regex

```
[\*?[)\]]
```

If you want to remove the brackets and price inside use the following regex

```
[\[].*?[)\]]
```

Also, you can use regexr.com for testing

http://regexr.com/3dd0l